# VBA Division with 4 decimal

Tags: vba, ms-word

i'm ripping my hair with the following problem:

In Microsoft Word VBA, I have this division:

5.85 / 100 , the result displayed it's 0,058

The real result it's 0,0585.

->>>>>> I need the result to display 0,0585 or 0,059

What I need to do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Format$(5.85 / 100, "#.####")`

Comment: Use can use Format(5.85 / 100, "0.000"). Using 0 will ensure one zero before decimal.

Comment: Please include your code. How else can we know where / how it's displayed and test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like :

```
Dim MyNumber As Double

MyNumber = CDbl(Format$(5.85 / 100, "#.####"))

MsgBox MyNumber
```

Comment: It will work that way cuz the string format that is returned is gonna be automatically converted to double cuz it fits that format !!!
And if I did this it was intentional to avoid declaring 2 variables and confuse him, he seems a beginner

Comment: Good programming practices are just as important (if not more so) for beginners. Thanks to you with the sloppy answer here, there will be a future question "Why does `Format(varA) + Format(varB)` give me a wrong answer?" - and this will be because the OP not only did not pick up that `Format` returns a `String` but because your code is deliberately misleading in implying that `Format` returns a `Double`!

Comment: His question was to print the result of 5.85 / 100, not to make aritmetic operations and compute values. Read the question, before criticizing an answer. What I provided is an answer to his problem. Following your logic, why not to each him how to make graphical functions in vba ? he may need that one day ! yes one day, but not for his question right above...a beginner who is not professionnal need something simple to solve his problem, not to complicate things by providing too much information that he may never use.

Comment: You have totally missed the point of my comment. Amd the point of my current downvote (which you still have  a chance to address). If you are going to teach someone a simple snippet, then teach it correctly. I am not asking you to embellish it and I didn't say anything about "graphics" - so why bring it up? All I am asking is that you correct your code snippet which has some obvious flaws.

Answer (score 0):

Prints 0,0585

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim a As Double

a = 5.85 / 100
Debug.Print a
End Sub
```